How can I pass a variable to my other function in flask backend?
I am currently building a vocabulary trainer for my assignment. I'm using flask and javascript in the backend.
One function retrieves the vocabulary ID primary key from the database, and I need it in another function to update the difficulty of the Vocab with the SQL Selector.
Here are the code snippets:
@app.route("/learn", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def lernen():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        word_id = request.form.get('word_id')
        user_answer = request.form.get('user_answer')
        lang = request.form.get('lang')

        con = connect_db()
        cursor = con.cursor(dictionary=True)
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Vokabelna WHERE Nummer = %s", (word_id,))
        word = cursor.fetchone()

        if not word:
            cursor.close()
            return render_template("learn.html", error="Word not found")

        correct_answer = word['Deutsch'] if lang == 'de-en' else word['Englisch']
        is_correct = user_answer.strip().lower() == correct_answer.strip().lower()

        feedback = "Correct!" if is_correct else f"Incorrect. The correct answer was: {correct_answer}"
        return render_template("learn.html", feedback=feedback, word=word, show_difficulty_buttons=True)

@app.route("/api/difficulty", methods=['POST'])
def update_difficulty():
    new_difficulty = request.get_json()
    con = connect_db()
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE Vokabeln set schwierigkeit = %s WHERE Nummer = %s", (new_difficulty, str(word_id)))
    con.commit()
    cursor.close()

    return jsonify({'message': 'Schwierigkeit updated successfully!'})

I thought about creating a global variable or returning it by itself. With word_id = word_id

Clarify how word_id is passed to update_difficulty. Consider using session or passing it in the request.

the same function can be executed by many users at the same time - keeping it as single variable makes no sense. So you may have to keep it in database (with user ID) or you may keep it in cookies, eventually you can send it in url (or as hidden input in <form>),
